# How do I download a renderas='pdf' visualforce page from java?

Tags: salesforce

Reading this page http://www.forcedisturbances.com/2012/07/downloading-visual-force-pages-that-are.html, I have tried this code but it does not seem to work for me.

```
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setUsername(USERNAME);
config.setPassword(PASSWORD);
connection = Connector.newConnection(config);

URL url = new URL("https://c.na14.visual.force.com/apex/ReportPrintOut?id=");
url.openConnection().addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + config.getSessionId());
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
```

I can verify that the salesforce connector object is successful because I do not get a invalid login exception thrown, and I can successfully query the data. The url data that is obtained from the URL call is the following, indicating a problem with the session id. However I cannot figure out what the problem is.

```
HTTP Code: 200
<script>
if (window.location.replace){ 
    window.location.replace('https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisualforce%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.na14.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252FReportPrintOut%253Fid%253D');
} else {;
    window.location.href ='https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisualforce%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.na14.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252FReportPrintOut%253Fid%253D';
} 
</script>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by replacing

```
url.openConnection().addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + config.getSessionId());
```

by

```
url.openConnection().setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + config.getSessionId());
```